# Update an existing route with a set of pedestrian crossings

Tags: google-maps, graph-algorithm

I am trying to route though a set of pedestrian crossings. I ask a route to the Google Maps service to get a default route, the problem with that route is that it does not include some waypoints (pedestrian crossings) (and re-requesting a route with found walkways as waypoints does not lead to satisfying results). I have the geocoordinates of each pedestrian crossing in the streets the route is requested (for each one, I have both endpoints coordinates).

To solve the problem, I approximate the lat,lon coordinates to (x,y) values which is correct for the accuracy I need. So a route is defined by a with a set of (x,y) coordinates.

I can decompose the problem in two sub-problems:

1) Finding which pedestrian crossings should be used to reach the destination

2) Update the existing route with the found pedestrian crossings

For 1), I defined some conditions about when to attach a crossing to a given route segment.

a. Each extremity of the pedestrian crossing should be max 10m far from the current segment

b. Each extremity is located “inside" the current segment (dot product of some extremity to segment begin and to segment end should be negative)

c. I only attach one crossing to a given route segment (others are rejected) It gives me a quite correct subset of pedestrian crossings but I am not sure if it is optimal ?

For 2) I have no clue about how to efficiently merge the found pedestrian walkways with the existing route (I started looking at the A* algorithm) ?

Here is some example of route from point A to point B (in orange the pedestrian crossings, in black the input route, in blue the expected output route).

[image]

Comment: Is this not just a [shortest-path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)?

Comment: I don't think it truly is because I don't have the coordinates of all sidewalks and the user should cross every street using a pedestrian walkway (or do you mean by affecting big distances to non crossings segments?)

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstood. I thought you had all the coordinates.

Comment: So if I get it well, you want to use the result of maps seach where waypoints do not appear, and mix this with the waypoints localisations in order to create a new result ? Seems like a strange idea, why not write your own shortest path solver ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I don't write my own shortest path solver because I guess it would require a huge database to store all the streets data / sidewalk, in my situation I delegate the pathfinding to an external service (Google Maps) and when I look at the returned route, I see that its too imprecise as it does not pass through the pedestrian crossings so I want to be able to simply update the route by adding a "pass through pedestrian crossings" requirement.